# iOS Nextpeer facebook integration issue

Tags: ios, facebook, multiplayer, nextpeer

I am trying to integrate Facebook with Nextpeer. When i tell nextpeer about successful login by these methods:

```
[Nextpeer loginWithFacebook];
[Nextpeer logoutFromFacebook];
```

I gives me warning on console

```
Nextpeer warning: Couldn't login Facebook user - no instance of NPFacebookBridgeDelegate provided.
```

I have also provided implementation for delegate methods of NPFacebookBridgeDelegate which are:

```
-(NPFacebookSession*) getCurrentFacebookSession;
-(void) destroyCurrentFacebookSession;
-(void) requestFacebookSessionWithPermissions:(NSArray*)permissions completionBlock:(void (^)(NPFacebookSession* session))completionBlock;
-(void) requestFacebookPermissions:(NSArray*)permissions completionBlock:(void (^)(NPFacebookSession* session))completionBlock;
```

but these never gets called. Anyone have any idea what am I missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed passing the NextpeerFacebookBridgeDelegate in the initializion phase, as the log said.

Read more here https://nextpeer.atlassian.net/wiki/display/NS/Facebook+Integration

Comment: Thanks for the answer

Comment: happy to help a fellow dev!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks.. I did it by changing init of nextpeer from

```
[Nextpeer initWithProductKey:];
```

To this:

```
[Nextpeer initializeWithProductKey:GAME_KEY andDelegates:[NPDelegatesContainer containerWithNextpeerDelegate:self tournamentDelegate:self facebookBridgeDelegate:self] ];
```